# How to remove local snapshots on mojave

Tags: backup, time-machine, mojave

Asking for a friend...

He's having issues with local snapshots being taken by Time Machine.  He doesn't want to disable Time Machine entirely, but due to disk space issues causing performance issues, he wants to have local snapshots disabled - he connects to the network regularly enough that the networked time machine does backups frequently enough.

On previous versions of MacOS, he could run the command

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

to only have the remote backups enabled.

This command aparrently does not work any more.  What can be done to configure the system in the same way?

Comment: This is a bit of a bug imho, and only happens with TM configurations using network mount backup destinations. It really shouldn't happen because the local snapshots are completely separate from the Time Machine backups in this case; the local snapshots in APFS systems are APFS snapshots, and not implemented as temporary Time Machine backups to a local hidden folder like it was before High Sierra. Which means that purging the snapshots should be an instant process, but if a backup was interrupted, macOS seems to be reluctant to purge those snapshots.

Comment: Use `diskutil ap snaps /` and `sudo diskutil deleteSnapshot / -uuid <snapshotUUID> | -xid <snapshotXIDNumber> | -name <snapshotName>` to force reclaim space, the UUID/XID/snapshotName are listed in the output of the `diskutil ap snaps /`command.

Comment: Not true - I have a grave problem where ALL my TimeMachine backup attempts fail, due to some problem in 2 files on specific localSnapshot. I'd like to delete a specific snapshot to resolve this, since I can't modify them and delete the problematic files

Comment: Minor syntax error in the second command (sudo diskutil) of @kumowoon1025 response above. It needs to include the ap (apfs) command after diskutil as in the first command (diskutil ap snaps /).

Answer (score 4):

I also had problems with running out of disk space due to Time Machine/APFS local snapshots and the macOS disk purging system not working quickly enough -- I didn't find a way of disabling local snapshots, but I did find the following commands can help, if making management a little more manual.

If you want to delete *all* local snapshots, the following command will work -- but it's possible the next Time Machine update will take longer as it will have to work out the differences between the last Time Machine backup and the current state of the drive.

```
sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots /
```

If you just want to delete *some* local snapshots, you can try the following command, the numbers I've used are completely arbitrary, I was just trying to force it to free up some space:

```
 sudo tmutil thinLocalSnapshots / 1000000000 3
```

The first value is the purge amount (1 GB in this case) you'd like `tmutil` to try and reclaim, the second value is the urgency, which can be from 1 to 4.  I've no idea which is more urgent, 1 or 4, it doesn't seem to be documented.  If you use this command repeatedly it will delete more snapshots each time, until they're all deleted.

Comment: For a more surefire way to delete apfs snapshots (which time machine uses as local snapshots on apfs volumes) use `diskutil` instead. `diskutil ap listSnaps /` shows you a list of snapshots, and indicates which snapshot "limits the minimum size of the APFS container." If the snapshot is also "Purgeable", then you can `sudo diskutil ap deleteSnapshot / -uuid UUID | -name name | -xid XID` to delete the snapshot without ambiguity. `tmutil` is more user friendly though, and the `urgency` goes from 1 - least urgent to 4 - most urgent.